# Unable to resolve host when trying to install mariadb

Tags: mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried following the instructions [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=datautama&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=trusty--ubuntu_trusty&version=10.1) to install in windows subsystem for linux having the release

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

the problem comes when I tried to run this command from their documentation

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'
```

I got this result

```
sudo: unable to resolve host
```

what is this mean?
what is the solution?

Comment: There are two other commands in the instruction which are also executed under `sudo` before the one that you pasted. Did you run them and they went well, or did you skip them (e.g. because you already had the key and the tool)? Can you run anything at all under sudo?

Comment: Yes, I already run the two, the command that I pasted is what I got the problem

Comment: So, you can't run this particular command **persistently**, but you can run everything else under `sudo`? Can you run, for example, `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb foo bar'`? (If you can, don't forget to remove this rubbish from the `sources.list` afterwards).

Comment: Thanks, I just remove this `[arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el]` from sources.list and it works